# class file for javax.activation.DataSource not found

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

There is no compilation error, but the moment I try to build it using maven it throws the following error and fails the build

I'm using Java 11 Open JDK

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project notification-functionapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] MailSender.java:[112,37] cannot access javax.activation.DataSource
[ERROR] class file for javax.activation.DataSource not found
```

At 112 line of MailSender.java this following line of code is there

```
  final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
```

Answer (score 3):

javax.activation seems to be not present inherently in Java 11 Open JDK, so if you encounter this error please add the following dependency in you pom.xml or build.gradle

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
compile 'com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0'
```

Comment: Encountered in the context of upgrading Sonatype Nexus OSS (2.15.1). No Java is bundled. I happened to select an Open Java 11. The javax namespace is no longer distributed (since 9/10?). So manually fulfilled the javax.xml.bind dependency; and subsequently repeated the same for javax.activation. Chasing technical debt.